# Do the inequalities matter in this case of the marginal probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have this probability density of $f(x,y)$ if $0\le x \lt y\le 1$ and I can't seem to get the right answer. It says in the back of my book that the bound's on the integral for say $f_X(x)$ is from $0$ to $x$. Shouldn't the integral to find the marginal density of $X$ be $$f_X(x)=\int_x^1 f(x,y)dy$$ Then it says the marginal for $Y$ is $$f_Y(y)=\int_y^1f(x,y)dx$$ Shouldnt this one be $$f_Y(y)=\int_0^yf(x,y)dx$$?? Im slightly confused now. Is it because $x$ is strictly less than $y$?

Comment: Books can have typographical errors in them, and the sections titled "answers to odd-numbered problems" or "solutions to odd-numbered problems" often have more such errors than the main text, perhaps because these sections are prepared last, in a rush by the author(s) or their teaching assistants, after the main text has been carefully written and re-written. Your integral for $f_Y(y)$ has the correct limits; the book's integral does not.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks that's what I thought. I knew that didn't look right. So glad I have a mathematical community to correct me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x,y)$ is the joint density of the random variables $X,Y$, then the marginal density of $X$ is
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{f(x,y)dy}
$$
Now, you know that $f(x,y)$ equals zero if $y<x$, or $x$ or $y$ falls outside the interval $[0,1]$ (or so I interpret your question) and thus the formula simplifies to
$$
f_X(x)=\int_x^1{f(x,y)dy}.
$$

Similarly one finds
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^y{f(x,y)dx}.
$$

Comment: Thank you that clears it up. My book has an error.